# Does an event keep an object alive?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Let's say I have this system:

```
public class AppController {
    public event Action LanguageChangedEvent;
}

public class UIElement {

    private AppController _appController = (some initialization);

    public UIElement() {
        _appController.LanguageChangedEvent += OnLanguageChanged;
    }

    public void OnLanguageChanged() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

As the event is kept alive, and it has a reference to the method in the UIElement class, it therefore has a reference to the UIElement object.

Does that reference keep the object alive?

Comment: What is `OnLanguageChanged`? Does it declared within `UIElement` class?

Comment: @Dennis: I'd guess an instance method of `UIElement` in this case.

Comment: @Dennis indeed it is an instance method of `UIElement`

Comment: Your "app" controller is very dangerous.  Use the *static* keyword where ever it is appropriate, it is here.  It flags global variables.  That helps you go "uh-oh", static events are a big red flag.

Comment: @HansPassant the app controller controls the flow of data in my app. It uses events to handle navigation, so that I can reuse the core for other programs (I am using Xamarin). Using events makes it very easy to perform all the necessary navigation and app logic in one place. The app controller is a singleton, which I left out here because it is not needed for the question.

Comment: "Singleton" is very often just double-speak for "global variable".  Google "singletons are evil" for decent articles that analyze the problem with them.

Comment: @HenkHolterman could you elaborate when and when not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `OnLanguageChanged` is an instance method, `_appController` holds a reference to the constructed `UIElement` instance.

While `_appController` is alive, `UIElement` instance is alive too.